# Не могу открыть Db файл в Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

```
    QSqlDatabase db;
    db.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    QString path = QDir::currentPath();
    path += QString("/chatLog.db");

    qDebug() << path;

    db.setDatabaseName(path);

    if (!db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Cant open db";
    }
    else
    {
        QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM chat");

        while (query.next())
        {
            qDebug() << query.value(1).toString();
        }
    }
```

Вот код для подключения Sql Lite файла но не может открыть
Db файл в правильном директории 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В папке с exe нужно файл базы данных хранить, либо указывать конкретный полный путь до файла

Comment: да я так и делаю но не видит этот файл или не может открыть

Comment: дык, посмотри, почему открыть не получается: `db.lastError().text()`

Comment: Да, базу надо класть не рядом с экзешником, а в каталог, откуда он запускается. В зависимости от настроек проекта, эти два местоположения могут отличаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//QSqlDatabase db;
//db.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
// причина ошибки
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

QString path = QDir::currentPath();
path += QString("/chatLog.db");

qDebug() << path;

db.setDatabaseName(path);

if (!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Cant open db";
}
else
{
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM chat");

    while (query.next())
    {
        qDebug() << query.value(1).toString();
    }
}
```